# How to avoid parallel trees

Tags: c#, design-patterns, mvvm, repository-pattern

In many applications I use the repository pattern and a bunch of classes representing my model.

The repository accomplishes reading and writing (CRUD) to a database leveraging my own model objects. Often these data are hierachical in some way, e.g. master-details views etc.

But then I often end up with parallel trees of classes, having one tree in the model and one tree in the viewmodels. This feels like a design-flaw.

Is there a way to avoid that? How can this be expressed better?

Comment: This question is not about inheritance hierarchies and not java!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can't see anything bad here. It's OK to have hierarchical view models/views, just as it is normal for models. Moreover, there can be more than one VM hierarchies, depending on use-cases.

If requirements for your application contains some master data, detail data and you need display them, you can't throw master view and detail view in general.

Comment: Thought there could be a more clever way of writing the repository or something like that. Hierachical data is just natural in most cases, but it gives those "ugly" parallel trees